# Echo Facebook user name and photo?

Tags: php, javascript, json, facebook, api

Im trying to make a welcome page, where Facebook logged users, when they visit my webpage, they can see their name and photo, with a text like "Welcome to our page, Facebook_USER_NAME"

Is it possible or Facebook don't have any API's available for this?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Have you tried to google for "facebook API"? And if not, why haven't you?

Comment: Off course my friend, that was the first step...but im not used to facebook api's at all, that's why im asking to the Pro's

Comment: so haven't you found millions of tutorials including the ones on an official FB developers portal?

Comment: IF i had, I didn't need to make this question...

Comment: show us what you have used as a search query for google. Because I've tried several random and google gave me pretty expected results

Comment: "facebook echo logged name" but thanks anyway.. axel already answered my question.

Comment: If I put exactly your query to the google I see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/ as a first result. The straightforward example. Sometimes it worth reading the search results after you performed a search

Comment: Like I said bellow, I didn't want the app solution but a easy solution just for logged users see themselves when they visit one of my webpages. I don't want any information about them, the only thing I wanted was a "personal welcome"...the main question was if that was possible in the first place...it's a client side solution, that I thought that was possible.

Comment: if an official documentation states that you have to have an app, then you must have it. It's that simple.

Comment: Im sorry but your answers look more a lecture than a helpful answer. With just a few lines, Axel gave the perfect answer for people who are not used to Facebook API's and don't want to read a full documentation on how they work. Because, once again, the solution that I needed was simple since it was a "client side echo information" and not something that I needed access to collect their data like Facebook web applications work.

Comment: it's a lecture about advantages of reading, indeed. These days newbie developers are too lazy to read tools' documentation.

Comment: It's not about being lazy or newbie but to know if someone know some workarounds for this simple task. Because making a web application for this simple task it was something that I didn't wanted in the first place. If people want to be helpful, reply... if don't, ignoring it's always a great option.

Comment: "Because making a web application" --- no one required to create a "web application", but a "facebook application". That only proves what I said - you're solving the issue, while haven't read even basics.

Comment: As far as I know a "facebook app" it's a "web app" also, but if you didn't get what I've tried to say, it's not my fault. Axel on his answer used exacly the same definition and I didn't needed too much to understand that he was talking about the "facebook app". Have a nice day.

Comment: "As far as I know a "facebook app" it's a "web app" also" --- not even close. Facebook app may be created for a linux console application, which is not web app in any way. "but if you didn't get what I've tried to say, it's not my fault." --- if only you used correct terms. Right, for that you need to read a documentation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a web application and register that on FB.
The user needs to grant access to his FB profile with this application.
Then, the application may retrieve information about the users profile like name or profile picture.

You can do that by php, java or even javascript. Just look here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/apis/

BUT: as long as the user has not granted acces actively to his/her profile by your app, you are unable to access ANY data from FB.

So what gimmick should that be?

Comment: Thanks Axel, that was the perfect answer! I tought that we could use a simple code just to "echo/print" to the user his own name and photo (info only to them) just to make a Welcome page like the old fashion ones when we asked them, their names (using javascript). Nothing too much useful, but great for giving them a "personal welcome" when they visit one of our pages.